# Woocommerce forcing checkout through PayPal Express Payments instead of PayPal Standard

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

I have a website built on Woocommerce, and the only payment gateway set up is PayPal Payments Standard which comes with Woocommerce.  This typically allows customers to checkout using a credit card without creating a PayPal account (and I have it working on similar websites).  However, on this site, WC is forcing checkout through PP Payments Express.  I have spoken with PP support, and they said it appears to be the site itself vs. settings within the client's PP account.

**I have:**

- Disabled all plugins except WC to rule out a conflict
- Tested it using the default TwentySeventeen theme to rule out
  something in the theme itself.
- Updated to the latest version of WC to rule out some glitch in the existing plugin

Answer (score 0):

Any API request is done through the site. For express Checkout, it seems that the plugin you are using is forcing this. You would need to contact the plugin developer or make sure that any other Paypal plugins are disabled.